Animated series in which a group of friends transform into superheroes when they touch aliens/monsters
I watched this show in the 2010s.
This show had a group of friends. They transform into superheroes when they touch the aliens/monsters. The protagonist had a blue color suit. If they are injured, they can't transform. I remember this because the girl in the gang couldn't transform when she was injured. The show had five heroes; only one of them is a girl.

Hi, welcome to the site. Was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

Sounds somewhat like Digimon Frontier, though I think that was a team of six.

It's not Digimon frontier. I'm not sure if it was 2d or 3d.

Is it Virus Attack (2011)?
IMDB's summary says:

When an alien virus threatens the earth turning people into virus like monsters, five teenage heroes form a team to stop the virus attack.

The characters have to come into contact with the monsters to transform.



